# multicast and broadcast push notification

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, push-notification, broadcast, multicast

I'm looking for a way to send a multicast or broadcast push notification to multiple wp7 devices just like in iphone, but didnt find any code sample or any documentation. I'm using C# language.
Can it be that there's no such concept in windows phone ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multicast Push notifications are currently not supported by Microsoft Push notifications service. You will have to iterate through all of your subscriptions and send one push to each individually.

There's however, a tutorial for sending some sort of broadcast to WP8 devices using azure.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/mobile/tutorials/push-notifications-to-users-wp8/

And this is a developers guide to WP7 for iPhone/Android developers. There is a chapter that covers push and explains WP7 push in the context of an iPhone app.

http://www.docstoc.com/docs/114462919/Windows-Phone-7-Guide-for-Android-Application-Developers